# rgl: how to display the numbers of all opened rgl devices

Tags: r, rgl

`rgl.cur()` returns the current rgl device number and `rgl.set()` allows to set a device as the active one. I cannot find an `rgl` function that returns all opened devices like `dev.list()` for standard graphic devices. Is there a function I missed to get an overview of the all opened rgl devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `rgl.dev.list()` returns all device IDs of opened rgl devices. Is this what you're after?